# Openwrt allow multicast traffic

Tags: linux, multicast, multicastsocket

I'm running openwrt on a device and have a python script that listens and prints to screen multicast traffic on 239.2.1.1.

However nothing is being printed to the screen and I believe this is a firewall issue. 
How do I make sure that multicast traffic is being allowed in on a lan interface running openwrt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it is bit late, but i guess it will help someone who is still looking for answer.

Install IGMPProxy

```
install igmpproxy
make menuconfig
 -> Network                                                                                                                                                            
  -> Routing and Redirection
```

Look for the package here in bin folder
`AR9331 hardware:- bin/ar71xx/packages/base/igmpproxy_0.1-9_ar71xx.ipk`

```
copy the ipk to openwrt router.
opkg install igmpproxy
/etc/init.d/igmpproxy start
```

Ensure you got this section in the `/etc/config/firewall`

```
config rule
        option name             Allow-IGMP
        option src              wan
        option proto            igmp
        option family           ipv4
        option target           ACCEPT
```

Ensure you got this section in /etc/config/igmpproxy

```
config igmpproxy
        option quickleave 1

config phyint
        option network wan
        option direction upstream
        list altnet 0.0.0.0/0

config phyint
        option network lan
        option direction downstream
```

Ensure the below in network config

```
In /etc/config/igmpproxy
config interface lan
        option igmp_snooping 1
```

Also enable in br-lan

```
echo "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br-lan/bridge/multicast_snooping
```